# How do i add &debug=true?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, prometheus

I'm doing a curl and I want to get more details about the errors, and for that I should use `&debug=true` but I dont know where to put it and how.

This is the curl that I'm using and which I want to get more details about the errors :

```sh
curl -s "localhost:9115/probe?target=http://linux.org&module=http_2xx" | grep -v '^#'
```

Comment: You could try reference the [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php). If you cant get it to work this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl) outlines how to use cURL correctly as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a separator; add `debug=true` just like you added `module=http_2xx`.

```
curl -s "localhost:9115/probe?target=http://linux.org&module=http_2xx&debug=true" | grep -v '^#'
```